# How to get redux store value without component?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I want to get store value directly in my action file.

Here is my reducer file

ServiceReducer.js

```
import {
  // other actions
  RESET_SERVICE_UPDATE_STATUS
} from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  serviceData: [],
  modalVisable: false, 
  modalMsg: '',
  updateStatus: null
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    // the other actions
    case RESET_SERVICE_UPDATE_STATUS:
      return {
        ...state,
        updateStatus: action.updateStatus
      };
    default:
      return state;
    }
};
```

Here is my action file

ServiceAction.js

```
// I try to import the reducer
import ServiceReducer from '../reducers/ServiceReducer';
import { 
  // other actions
  RESET_SERVICE_UPDATE_STATUS
} from './types';

export const resetServiceUpdateStatus = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    console.log('What is ServiceReducer', ServiceReducer);
    // dispatch({ type: RESET_SERVICE_UPDATE_STATUS, updateStatus: null });
  };  
};
```

I console.log the reducer, I can't see any store value that I can get.

[image]

Here is my reducer file index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
// other reducers
import ServiceReducer from './ServiceReducer';

export default combineReducers({
  // other reducer
  ServiceRedux: ServiceReducer
});
```

I try the code in my action, but just get original initial state value.

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducers from '../reducers';

const store = createStore(reducers);

console.log('what is store', store.getState());
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How do you get the store anywhere else? By importing it from somewhere, right?

Comment: I get the store value with `connect` in component.

Comment: And when you create your provider... There's a store, right? Either created or imported? That's your store. That said: why would you need the store in a reducer?

Comment: Hmm... Because I can  get it and send data to reducer through actions ?

Comment: You're logging it immediately after creation--what did you expect you see? It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish here. Inn any case, that's your store--you can export it and access it wherever you want.

Comment: I just want to get my store value without `connect`, For instance, If I create a pure js file, how do I get the store value I had created.

Comment: ... You export it from where you create it, and import it from where you want to use it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Redux without React. `react-redux` is just API for easier manipulation with Redux in React.

You should create your store in separate file, e.g. `store.js`:

```js
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducers from '../reducers';

const store = createStore(reducers);

export default store;
```

And then whenever you need your state of the store, import `store` from `store.js` and call [store.getState()](https://redux.js.org/api/store#getstate):

some js file:

```js
import store form './store';

// get current state
console.log('what is currently in store', store.getState());
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I try to create my store in separate file just like yours.  I still get initial state values.  ( My store had been changed, it should not be initial state. )

Comment: @Morton Without context it's impossible to know what you're talking about. You will get whatever state the store is in when you log it, period.

Comment: @Morton as DaveNewton states try to add some example when it is not working in your case. It should work. Check if you are really dispatching some action and if you are really handling it in reducer before you log your current state.